# How does a coroutine control where it yields to?

Tags: python, coroutine

Generators differ from functions/subroutines in the ability, if invoked repeatedly, to resume from the line at which they last returned, rather than restarting from the top.

Whilst generators always yield control back to their invoking routine, [apparently](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr)* *coroutines* only differ by the ability to control where they transfer execution to.

How does this work, and *how is it different from subroutine calls* (which also temporarily suspend the execution of the current subroutine, while controlling where execution is immediately passed)?

---

<sub>* *"All of this makes generator functions quite similar to coroutines; they yield multiple times, they have more than one entry point and their execution can be suspended. **The only difference** is that a generator function cannot control where the execution should continue after it yields; the control is always transferred to the generator’s caller."* -- Python manual, v2.5-3.7 (ever since yield-expressions introduced).</sub>

<sub>Also, Conway's originating (1963) [description](http://www.melconway.com/Home/pdf/compiler.pdf) of coroutines involved them passing control to each other using a symmetric syntax, resembling calls to input/output functions. (Similarly, Knuth *The Art of Computer Programming 3rd Ed* gives the example of a coroutine for each player in a game of chess, describing that *"it is impossible to distinguish which is a subroutine of the other"* because both coroutines invoke the other like a subroutine.)</sub>

Comment: Not really. Generators are coroutines that never lookup the value returned by the `yield` expressions.

Comment: What exactly makes you think that coroutines have the ability to control where they transfer execution to?

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coroutine-in-python/

Comment: @martineau source cited in question; I've edited to include relevant quote.

Comment: benjimin: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I still don't quite understand how could be done. I think it may have something to do with coroutines being able to `yield` another coroutine — like `yield from another_coroutine()` — but am not sure. Would be nice to see an example of what the documentation is talking about.

Comment: In other words, by `yield`ing from another coroutine,  execution continues in it rather than returning to the caller of the current coroutine.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the confusion here is that the term "coroutine" is often applied loosely. The original descriptions of coroutines implied a group of code blocks that can symmetrically and selectively transfer control to resume each other from wherever they had left off. Still, it was only a low level of structure (in an era when concepts like subroutine call stacks were still being developed) and left several details unspecified. In particular, if coroutines are able to suspend and resume even from within nested subroutine calls then a separate memory stack needs to be managed for each (to avoid fragmentation), and so they would constitute cooperative multitasking (a.k.a. fibers or lightweight/micro/green/user threads, enabling general concurrency within a single preemptive OS thread). Alternatively, if coroutines only pass control among each other from their top level (not nested routines) then they can all share the existing stack.

As noted in the python docs, yield-expressions (i.e. `y = yield x` in a generator routine) almost completely satisfy the notion of a stackless coroutine, but in an asymmetric manner. The calling code and the generator routine are each able to relinquish control to resume the other (from where it last was), and to pass and receive values from each other. However, the syntax is asymmetric (the caller uses e.g. `send` whereas the callee uses `yield`) and so the relationships form a loop-free hierarchy or tree graph (so a nested sub-generator cannot yield/send directly to its grandparent caller without the explicit coordination of the intervening parent generator).

Symmetric stackless coroutines can be implemented by launching python generators from a "trampoline" (event-loop), and having the generators yield tokens to instruct the loop which generator to iterate next. (For example, this could allow using coroutines to model multiple players taking turns in a card game like UNO.) Alternatively, a "scheduler" event-loop could be made responsible for deciding which coroutine to resume next, e.g. letting the tasks performed by different "coroutines" progress asynchronously.

Also, a "coroutine" could coordinate for all its event-loop communication to be delegated to a nested sub-"coroutine" until that terminates. This is sort of a coroutine analog of a subroutine call. In python, `await` or `yield from` is syntax sugar for this delegation.

Async functions (Python's so-called "native coroutines") use `await` expressions effectively to construct a kind of call stack (presumably in the form of linked awaitable objects on the heap). At some stage the current innermost nested awaitable object will yield control back to the scheduler, and the scheduler may decide to pass control to a totally separate coroutine stack. In python it is left up to libraries (such as `curio` or `asyncio`) to implement both the master event-loop and the primitive awaitable objects which communicate to the event-loop.

(There also exist async generators. These co-opt the exception system to be able to transfer control back just to the parent routine, while still also being able to delegate yielding to the event-loop.)

**Do coroutines control where they yield to?**

In comp-sci theory, yes; but in python, only sort-of.

If there are only two routines executing in concert (e.g. one generator plus the routine that iterates it) then the question is moot anyway. The original use-case for coroutines was to run successive stages of a data processing pipeline concurrently i.e. streaming through nested generators (minimising latency and temporary storage compared to multi-pass algorithms); for such chain-topologies, the asymmetric syntax of nested python generators does indeed enable choice of which routine resumes next.

In general however, python coroutines (particularly async functions) need an event-loop to control where execution gets transferred next. Normally async functions exercise no control over what resumes when.

**How does this compare with subroutine calls?**

Calls and yields are both ways to suspend the current routine.

In a sequence of subroutine calls, the caller is suspended but the callee is restarted each time from the first line. (The callee cannot return control to the caller without terminating itself.)

An algorithm involving exactly two coroutines can be expressed in python as a generator (with `yield` expressions) and a subroutine (with e.g. calls to the `send` method); in that sense a subroutine can be a coroutine.

The "native coroutines" (async functions) actually seem designed to imitate ordinary subroutines, just with support for concurrency (but without imposing parallelism nor preemption, potentially alleviating the burden of ensuring routines are reentrant/threadsafe). They facilitate task management; the `await` expressions specify networks of dependencies among tasks, and encourage writing individual tasks (and subtasks) in a procedural style (rather than explicitly passing callbacks, etc).